# Powershell script does nothing, silently, on domain joined machine, runs normally on non-domain machines

Tags: powershell

A powershell script we wrote that touches the file system and sql server will not run on a machine that is joined to a windows 2012r2 domain joined box, but it runs fine in another environment where the network is peer to peer. I'm guessing that some AD policy is preventing it from running, but there is no such message. When I execute the script from ISE on windows 10, it seems to do nothing. It should push some message into the debug window, but nothing shows up.

current settings

Scope ExecutionPolicy

MachinePolicy       Undefined

UserPolicy       Undefined

Process       Undefined

CurrentUser    RemoteSigned

LocalMachine    Unrestricted

when I turned on local machine unrestricted, I got a message saying the policy would be enabled but there was an overriding environment policy which would prevent it from being implemented. That's fine, I don't expect to run under that setting, it was just an experiment.

CurrentUser    RemoteSigned

is what all of the other machines I have run it on work with. All of the folders seem to have the required permissions. In any case there is nothing reported back re problems...except in the case of "LocalMachine    Unrestricted".

If AD is coming into play why no message? The AD environment is about as close to out of the box msft settings as you could get. The account that this is being run under doesn't seem to matter, as all result in the same thing, no action, all the way up to domain admin role.

A local file with a simple script like
Write-Host 'Hello, World!'
runs normally.

Am I forgetting something? I'm very new to powershell so it is likely to be something basic.

Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 5.1.19041.1320
InstanceId       : 493eefe0-892e-4104-af81-fde31772a0de
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Answer (score 1):

It just needed this

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
```

I hadn't configured the other machines involved so I didn't realize this was needed.